# How to update fields of a new node created using Rules?

Tags: 7, rules, entities

I have created a content type called Tasks that helps me track things I need to do on my site. I am trying to create a rule that when some content is published, a new task item is created reminding me to do some follow up work.

I created a rule that when the new content is published, a new task item is created.  I did this by adding Create a new entity to the Actions section.  I can give the item a title and set the author, but I can't figure out how to update the other fields in the new Tasks item.

Can this be done using rules or do I have to write PHP code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In Rules you have to add those fields as conditions - "Entity has x,y,z field" - then they will become available for your actions

Comment: So I started doing this, but I don't understand what I have to put in for Data Selector.

Comment: Add condition "Entity Has field" and select the field. Save, you will be prompted to add the Data Selector. The dropdown will contain something like: `site:... (Site information)
node (created content)
node:... (created content)` drill down to the most specific selector without a colon at the end. You probably want `node (created content)` then Save

Comment: see https://drupal.org/node/1300042 for documentation for data selection

Comment: I added the Entity has field Parameter: Entity: [node], Field: body condition. But my Create new entity action does not have any option to populate the body field of the new entity. Any suggestions other than php code?

Comment: Oh, you have to use the set a data value action. Huh.

Answer (score 1):

To "*update the other fields in the new Tasks item*" (as in your question), you can perfectly do this by extending the current list of Rules Actions you already have to "Create an entity" (of type *node*).

Here is a typical set/sequence of Rules Actions to get the job done, say for also updating 3 other fields of the node to be created:

- Create a new entity (Entity type = Node), which is the Rules Action you already must have in place to create your *Task*.
- Set a data value for `field1` of the created entity (pick whatever value for it that fits).
- Set a data value for `field2` of the created entity (pick whatever value for it that fits).
- Set a data value for `field3` of the created entity (pick whatever value for it that fits).
- Save the entity (make sure to use "*Force saving immediately*").

For an example of a rule (in Rules export format) with a similar set of Rules Actions (for only 1 such field), refer to [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/204763/39516) to "[Set value on newly created node using Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/204757/39516)".

Obviously, for this there is no need for any custom PHP code.