# Set value on newly created node using Rules

Tags: 7, rules

This is what I have now:
Content type 123 has a Entity Reference field referencing content type XYZ.
If new content is created of type XYZ then Rules creates new content of type 123.
So by creating 1 new node (of type XYZ) I get one extra of type 123.

This is what I'm missing:
How do I set the Entity Reference field of 123 correctly by using Rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Rules action you need to use the `Set a data value` action. This can be used to enter data in fields and properties. Make sure to set the value of your new 123-entity to refer to the xyz entity.

```
{ "rules_create_new_basic_page_after_saving_article" : {
    "LABEL" : "Create new basic page after saving article",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--article" : { "bundle" : "article" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "param_type" : "page",
            "param_title" : "Basic page to go with [node:title]",
            "param_author" : [ "node:author" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "page_created" : "Created basic page" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "page-created:field-reference-to-other-entity-" ],
          "value" : [ "node" ]
        }
      },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "page-created" ], "immediate" : "1" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you do this in a single rule? If not, which Rules Event would you use for the additional rule? Also, which value, or token, would you use to set the value?

Comment: `Would you do this in a single rule?` Personal preference, I probably would. `Which value, or token, would you use to set the value` The value of the xyz entity. The rules data selector is pretty powerful and it will guide you in selecting the right property.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens your second question was already in the original answer `Make sure to set the value of your new 123-entity to refer to the xyz entity.`

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens OP already managed to create a node after saving a new one (so I am assuming the `after saving a new node` event). This way both nodes are already available in that single rule. Simply add an action below the creation of the new node to set the data value, then save the node again.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens you are free to write your own answer if you feel mine would not work. It is updated with a proof of concept. Here is the simplytest.me page: https://dr3br.ply.st it will run for another 23 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, interesting! Even without any rules condition needed (as in your original answer). I look forward to OPers feedback about it also. PS: and it answers my original comment. So +1

Comment: Thanks Neograph. This is exactly the solution I was looking for. Give me some time to rewrite it to fit my custom values.

Comment: Already fixed it. Wonderful. Thanks again Neograph.